# How can I store a string of characters using friend operators?

Tags: c++, friend, getline

I'm trying to create a program that uses  [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) using class inheritance, but friend operator does not let me use getline. I've tried looking up different methods of overloading getline but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (I've only recently stopped using the namespace std so there's probably a couple of errors there).

It's still a work in progress. I don't know if I need length, or that if those overloaded + operators will actually add extra words to an old string, for example (though I can figure that out later, I just want to know how I can use getline properly here). Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Sentence{

    private:
        std::string codeSentence;
        int length;

    public:
        Sentence();
        Sentence(std::string codeSentence);
        Sentence(const Sentence &obj);
        ~Sentence();
        void setS (std::string codeSentence);
        std::string getS() const;
        Sentence & operator = (const Sentence &obj);
        Sentence operator +(const Sentence &obj) const;
        Sentence operator +(std::string codeSentence) const;
        friend Sentence operator +(std::string codeSentence, const Sentence &obj);
        friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Sentence &obj);
        friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in, Sentence &obj);
        friend std::istream & getline (std::istream & in, const Sentence & obj);
    };

Sentence::Sentence(){
}

Sentence::Sentence(const Sentence &obj){
    (*this) = obj;
}

Sentence::Sentence(std::string codeSentence){
    this->codeSentence = codeSentence;
}

Sentence::~Sentence(){
}

void Sentence::setS(std::string codeSentence){
    this->codeSentence = codeSentence;
}

std::string Sentence::getS() const{
    return (this-> codeSentence);
}

Sentence & Sentence::operator=(const Sentence &obj){
    this->codeSentence = obj.codeSentence;
    return (*this);
}

Sentence Sentence::operator+(const Sentence &obj) const{
    return (Sentence(this->codeSentence + ' ' + obj.codeSentence));
}

Sentence Sentence::operator+(std::string codeSentence) const{
    return (Sentence(this->codeSentence + ' ' + codeSentence));
}

Sentence operator+(std::string codeSentence, const Sentence &obj){
    return (Sentence(codeSentence + ' ' + obj.codeSentence));
}

std::istream & getline (std::istream & in, const Sentence & obj){
    if (in >> obj.length)
        getline(in, obj.codeSentence);
    return (in);
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in, Sentence &obj){

    in.getline(obj.codeSentence, sizeof(obj.codeSentence));
    return (in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `getLine` is that you're modifying the `Sentence` which is passed in as `const`. Just take away the `const`; you WANT to modify it after all.